# dummy instrumental variable for poisson

Tags: stata, poisson-regression

I have two questions:

1. Is there any specific technique/command in Stata to allow for the introduction a dummy variable as an instrument in `ivpoisson`. Is it at all possible?
2. How to test for exogeneity of instruments when using `ivpoisson`.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1355860-dummy-instrumental-variable-for-ivpoisson).

Answer (score 1):

Dummy instruments just need to be prefixed by `i.`, like this:

```
webuse website
ivpoisson gmm visits ad (time = i.female)
```

They require no other treatment.

You can't test exogeneity of an instrument. It's an assumption, usually justified by theory and institutional knowledge. You can, however, test that a particular regressor is endogenous, assuming you have a good instrument.